# Crystal Report Error : "Missing Param Values" while providing param from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, parameters, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal reports in my web application. My problem is when i keep EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="true" and EnableParameterPrompt="true" and provide information in prompted box my report works fine. but when i keep them false and provide information from code behind it always gives an error that "Missing Param Values" or "Database Logon Failed".

My code is as below :

Aspx file:

```
       <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="True" 
            GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" 
            ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" 
            ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="903px" 
            ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" 
            EnableParameterPrompt="False" />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
       ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();           
       reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
       string s=@"4EVER3-PC\MSSQLSERVER2";
       reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("db", "pwd", s, "databasename", true);
       reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@bankACId", "0");
       reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@fromDate", "4/11/2011 17:01:57");
       reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@todate", "4/11/2014 17:01:57");

       CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
       CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

please make a point what is wrong with this code. it is drivig me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

resolved the logon failed error.

I was accessing the database from another pc and its firewall was not allowing me to connect through crystal report. so i added sql server management studio to the list of allowed programs by firewall. So now connection problem is resolved.

So crystal report without any parameter works fine. but when i pass parameters it force closes the debug server..Any idea what should be the problem.

This is the half  answer of my question which may be helpful to those who are facing connection problems.

Answer (score 0):

Aspx FIle :

```
  <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="True" 
            Height="1202px" 
            ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Code Behind :

```
 protected void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       LoadReport();           
    }

    private void LoadReport()
    {
        doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrSalesReport.rpt"));

        doc.SetDatabaseLogon(AppConfig.ReportServerDSUserName, AppConfig.ReportServerDSPassword, AppConfig.ReportServerDomain, "TexERP", false);

   doc .SetParameterValue("@bankACId", "0");
   doc .SetParameterValue("@fromDate", "4/11/2011 17:01:57");
   doc .SetParameterValue("@todate", "4/11/2014 17:01:57");

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
    }
```

Comment: i dont have appConfig as i'm working in web app. so any idea how to get it in web app ??

Comment: reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("db", "pwd", s, "databasename", False);

Comment: write this line insted of the my line

Comment: r u add the parameter in .rpt file ?

Comment: yes i have added param also and as i mentioned in my question it is working fine if i provide param from prompted box. but it is not taking values from code behind.

Comment: r u add autodatabind property ?

Comment: i have edited my question . please have a look at that. and if you find anything wrong please point it out...

Comment: tried it.. but then it is prompting me to enter values for my parameters..:(

Comment: @SachinTrivedi: set the property EnableParameterPrompt="false"